# How to convert string data into integer using json module in dictionary?

Tags: python, json

I am controlling a smart light bulbs and publishing their status in UI dashboard, as a status I am getting a string data of "ON" and "OFF", but instead of this string data I want to get an integer data of 1 and 0, is there anyway I can convert this string data into integer data using JSON module in Python Dictionary.

Some of The API code of my smart Bulbs is here:

```
 if (_deviceUrl.getcode() == 200):
     data = _deviceUrl.read().decode("utf-8")
     # Use the json module to load the string data into a dictionary
     _theJSON = json.loads(data)
     # 1. status
     devicedata['on'] = self.on_dict[_theJSON["action"]['on']]
     # 2. brightness convert to %
     devicedata["bri"] = int(round(float(_theJSON["action"]["bri"]) * 100 / 255, 0))
```

Comment: The usual way is to use the `int()` function: i.e. `int("123")` -> `123`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following construction:

```
devicedata["on"] = 1 if _theJSON["action"]["on"] == "ON" else 0
```

It's pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

One way to replace a string with an integer like that is to define a separate dictionary:

```
ints = { 'OFF': 0, 'ON': 1 }
```

So for example if the value of `d['action']['status']` is the string "ON", then `ints[d['action']['status']]` returns the integer 1.